# How to omit/exclude files by extension in Intellij Show Usages

Tags: intellij-idea

In the following screenshot we see the results of selecting

> ```
> Edit|Find|Show Usages
> ```

while highlighting a class ***SparkAbstractBenchmark***:  Notice we do not get any useful information because ***the log files overwhelm the source files***

[image]

So is there a way to **exclude *.log** from the search ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider upgrading to the IntelliJ latest version, since in the newer versions the results are organized in sections that you can collapse/expand, I guess it could be usefull for this case, look:

[image]

If this is not enough (which is the case) you have the option to configure your own Scopes, just go to the **Find Usages Settings** and click the elipses in the **Scope** section, then click the **+** symbol to add a new (local) scope, name it and you should see this window:

[image: Find Usages Scope]

Then in the **Pattern:** field you have to specify the pattern following the [scope syntax](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/scope-language-syntax-reference.html) which should be something like this:`!file:*.log`

After applying you should have this new Scope option available in the settings scopes list which you can use to filter the search.

Comment: downloaded / installed latest from yesterday 7/21/15 IJ 14.1.4.   The problem i have is there are thousands of "junk" usages of the pattern I am looking for - so I do not have the chance to see the useful entries

Comment: I updated the answer, please follow those steps and let me know if it works for you

Comment: nice info! i am in a squeeze for time and will try in maybe 24 hours . but in the meantime i upvoted.